# Why is my jQuery preventDefault() working incorrectly?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress theme which uses a self-built jQuery accordion for navigation:

```
// jQuery Footer Navigation Slide
jQuery('#footer-accordion > li > a').on('click', function(e){
    if(jQuery(this).parent().has('ul')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
            jQuery('#footer-accordion li ul').slideUp(350);
            jQuery('ul li a').removeClass('open');
            jQuery(this).next('ul').slideDown(350);
            jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        } else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
            jQuery(this).next('ul').slideUp(350);
        }
    }
});
```

This worked just fine when i built it in bare HTML, I'm now however having trouble integrating it into my Wordpress theme. It seems the `e.preventDefault()` I've got in there is also preventing the default (follow the link) on menu items (`ul li a`) that do NOT have a `ul` inside. I figured my selectors were fine, since it worked in my HTML.

So in short: I expect to be directed to a page if I click a `ul li a` where the `li` has no nested `ul`. However, nothing happens when I do so. The `.slideUp()` function works just fine, and I can click the links that are in the nested `ul`. Are my selectors wrong? Am I giving the `wp_nav_menu()` function the wrong variables?

This is the relevant part from `footer.php`:

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container_class'   => 'footer-navigation clearfix',
        'menu_id'           => 'footer-accordion' 
)); ?>
```

And this is what Wordpress makes of that: http://jsfiddle.net/vKmfu/

Comment: Why don't you use a custom Walker Class for `wp_nav_menu`?

Comment: Because I don't know how. And this seemed like the easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery(this).parent().has('ul')` part is the culprit. This invocation always returns a jQuery object, like most of the jQuery functions. When a JavaScript object is used in a booelan context, it is evaluated as `true` unless it is `null`. What you need is    `if(jQuery(this).parent().has('ul').length > 0) { ... }`

By the way, the selector `'#footer-accordion > li > a'` won't affect the second or more level of links. The `>` is a `children` selector. You probably need a `descendant` selector.

Comment: That doesn't work, all of the links are clickable (even the ones with a nested `ul`) and none of them slide with that code added.

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake on my part. The `length` is a property and not a function. corrected the mistake.